# Update status problems

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I'm trying to update status. if status is 0 then on click it must update it to 1. but if status is 1 on click it must update it to 0.

my controller

```
public function status(Course $course)
{
    if ($course->status == 0) {
        $course->update(['status' => '1']);
        return redirect('/profile')->with('statusOn', 'status on!');
    } else {
       $course->update(['status' => '0']);
       return redirect('/profile')->with('statusOff', 'status off!');
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::post('/course/status/{course}', [CourseManagementController::class, 'status']);
```

blade

```
  <form method="POST" action="/course/status/{{$c->id}}">
                            @csrf
                            @if($c->status == 0)
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">active</button>
                            @else
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">deactive</button>
                            @endif
                        </form>
```

Comment: OK... and what's the problem? What happens when you test this code, and what do you need help with?

Comment: it's redirecting to profile page but status don't changes so i need to understand whats i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the method is getting executed? If you dd($course) into it you see the dd?

Comment: I don't see anything in your form which would change the status. The buttons you've shown, while they might have different colours and text, are functionally identical. You'd need to put a value on them which you could then read in the controller function, to see whether the activate or deactivate button was pressed.

Comment: In  dd($course) i'm getting current course #original: array:20 [▼
    "id" => 12
    "user_id" => 1
    "course_category_id" => 1
    "slug" => "asdasd23"
    "name" => "aveeee"
    "image" => "courses/20220106105310.png"
    "description" => "asdasdas"
    "body" => "asdasdd"
    "audio" => "asdasd"
    "price" => "213"
    "discount" => "123"
    "level" => 1
    "subtitle" => "asdasd"
    "certificate" => null
    "knowledge" => "asdasd"
    "status" => 0
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2022-01-06 10:53:10"
    "updated_at" => "2022-01-06 11:42:52"

Comment: @ADyson the controller checks for the current `$course->status` function and toggles it accordingly. No need to pass the `status` in the request.

Comment: @Alex gets it from where, though? That value presumably has to be posted back, and it's not in the form. Otherwise how does it get into $course object in the controller function? Admittedly I'm not very familiar with Laravel but I've used MVC frameworks and I'd expect you'd need to post it back. Or does it take some data from the DB before the "status" function is called?

Comment: @ADyson `status` is a column in the `courses` table, which `$courses->status` fetches. The `status` will be filled upon creation of the course.

Comment: @Alex `which $courses->status fetches`...and where's that called, in the OP's code?

Comment: @ADyson literally the first line of the `status` method; `if ($course->status == 0)`

Comment: @Alex sure, but how is $course->status actually _populated_? That's a property, not a function - it just gets a variable from the $course object...it cannot, by itself, request anything from the database. And as far as I can see, the `$course` object would be passed to the "status" function based on what's posted back from the form - because the route config sets it up to post the form to that action. Is there a step behind the scenes which can populate some data from the database for the given object, if it's missing in the form?

Comment: @ADyson it can in Laravel, that's a core piece of functionality of the framework. The `Course $course` parameter in the `status` method will fetch the correct model from the database according to the database and fill the object with the correct values from the database. Look up "route model binding".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240824/discussion-between-alex-and-adyson).

Comment: @Alex I see, thanks. Not something I've come across in other MVC frameworks I've used, in my experience you'd have to write something specific in the action function to do that. Otherwise it would just populate the model from only the data posted from the form. That's useful information, thankyou. I now think I understand the accepted answer below, as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there please debug !

```
public function status(Course $course)
{
    dump($course); // the data is okay or not

    if ($course->status == 0) {
        $status = $course->update(['status' => '1']);

        dd($status); // check the update status

        // return redirect('/profile')->with('statusOn', 'status on!');
    } else {
        $status = $course->update(['status' => '0']);

        dd($status); // check the update status

        // return redirect('/profile')->with('statusOff', 'status off!');
    }
}
```

If everything looks okay, please check `fillable` variable of your `Course` class, `status` might missing in `fillable` array

Comment: Thanks for answer. lol yes it was stupid mistake. i forgot status in fillable array )

Comment: Great to know, it's help, don't forget to vote :)